# Asp.net core 6 MVC RSA algorithm authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rsa

I am trying to integrate RSA token generation in my project

After login we are creating token:

```
public string CreateRSAToken(string userId)
    {
        string privateRsaKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\keys\\keypair.pem");

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", userId));

        RSAParameters rsaParams;
        using (var tr = new StringReader(privateRsaKey))
        {
            var pemReader = new PemReader(tr);
            var keyPair = pemReader.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
            if (keyPair == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not read RSA private key");
            }
            var privateRsaParams = keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
            rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateRsaParams);
        }
        using (var rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create())
        {
            rsa.ImportFromPem(privateRsaKey);
            Dictionary<string, object> payload = claims.ToDictionary(k => k.Type, v => (object)v.Value);
            var descriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = "",
                Claims = payload,//new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>() { ["sub"] = "1", ["UserId"] = 300 },
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256) { CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false } },
                IssuedAt = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                Expires = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(15),
            };
            var handler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            string token = handler.WriteToken(handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(descriptor));
            return token;
        }
        //using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        //{
        //    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
        //    Dictionary<string, object> payload = claims.ToDictionary(k => k.Type, v => (object)v.Value);
        //    string privateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Web\Core\IndraUI\IndraUI\wwwroot\keys\keypair.pem");
        //    string token = GetToken(privateKey, "", "1");
        //    return token;
        //}
    }
```

But I am getting unauthorized error whenever calling any method.
Earlier my code was working , for sha alorithm

Maybe i am missing something in my below code
`Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RsaSecurityKey>(provider =>
{    
    string publicKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\\wwwroot\\keys\\publickey.crt");
    publicKey = publicKey.Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", string.Empty);
    publicKey = publicKey.Replace("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n", string.Empty);
    
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(
        source: Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey),
        bytesRead: out int _
    );

    return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        SecurityKey rsa = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();

        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true; // <- great for debugging

        // Configure the actual Bearer validation
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = rsa,
            //ValidAudience = "jwt-test",
            //ValidIssuer = "jwt-test",
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true, 
            ValidateLifetime = true, 
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
        };
    });
```

**Calling method:**

```
public void GetData(string token)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:44440/home/GetIssuerCreditReports_User?userId=300&issuerId=1");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

Comment: When do you get `unauthorized error`? Are you able to generate the token? How are you passing token in the request?

Comment: i am generating token after login of user. Whenever i am calling any method passing token into that method. Each method call, i am getting unathorized error. Earlier similar code was working for SHA alorithm.

Comment: How do you pass the token to the method? Can you share the code which passes the token?

Comment: Updated in question